# what does a subscript next to a number, instead of a variable mean?

Tags: notation

I need to convert some numbers to binary, and I came across a number that had a subscripted number attached. The number in question was $35_{10}$. What does the subscripted 10 mean?

Comment: Scale of notation. Base 10 means for decimal system.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the number is written in base $10$. So, you should get that $35_{10}=100\,011_2$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.